# Create whole path automatically when writing to a new file with sub folders

Tags: java, path

I want to write a new file inside a folder that currently does not exist.

I use it like this:

```
File file = new File("C:\\user\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2\\filename.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

I get the file `filename.txt` under a folder called `dir1.dir2`.

I need `dir1/dir2`:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Please do not mark this question as duplicate because I didn't get what I need after a reseach.

**UPDATE 1**

I am using Jasper Report with Spring Boot to export a pdf file.

I need to create the file under a directory name the `current year`. Under this folder, I need to create a directory called `the current month`, and under this directory the pdf file should be exported. Example :

> (2018/auguest/report.pdf )

I am using `LocalDateTime` to get  `year` and `month`

Here is a portion of my code :

```
    ReportFiller reportFiller = context.getBean(ReportFiller.class);
    reportFiller.setReportFileName("quai.jrxml");
    reportFiller.compileReport();

    reportFiller = context.getBean(ReportFiller.class);
    reportFiller.fillReport();

    ReportExporter simpleExporter = context.getBean(ReportExporter.class);
    simpleExporter.setJasperPrint(reportFiller.getJasperPrint());

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    String dirName = simpleExporter.getPathToSaveFile() + "/"+ 
    localDateTime.getYear() + "/" + localDateTime.getMonth().name();
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    dir.mkdirs();
    String fileName = dirName + "/quaiReport.pdf";
    simpleExporter.exportToPdf(fileName, "");
```

Here is what I get :

[image]

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: @sajib I think I explained all.

Comment: you explaind what you do. but need to clearify what problem you face

Comment: @sajib instead of saving the file.pdf under a folder called `year.month`, I need to save the file under `year/month`. That's what I need. I tried many ways but I get the same result.

Comment: ok let me explain

Comment: i think you can got your problem now

Comment: i gave answer. just go your project directory you found your expected folder. Ide show it by `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create directory first then create file:

Like this:

```
String dirName = "/" + localDateTime.getYear() + "/" + localDateTime.getMonth().name();
    File file = new File(dirName);
    file.mkdirs();
    file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/quriReport.pdf");
    file.createNewFile();
```

If you go your project directory you see `2018/August/quriReport.pdf`

But `IDE` show subfolder with `.` if there is only `one subfolder`.

Comment: yes, that is it. It is how the IDE display sub folders :)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code which will work as per your expectation

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
FileWriter newFile = new FileWriter(file);
```

You need to create folder structure first and file next

Comment: It does not work. I get the same result.

Comment: but i ran in my local it works fine . Validate the directory name might have got dot instant of slash

Comment: I am using jasper report and spring boot and exporting to pdf file, maybe because of that. I updated the question

Comment: @AmirChoubani examine my answer

Comment: @Amir I see no problems in this code. How did it not work? What directories did you create?

Comment: @zhh with this code, I get one directory called dir1.dir2

Comment: @AmirChoubani Validate path you are creating the file. Above code should work and its not related boot or jasper your using . Atlast it will run on JVM.

Answer (score 1):

At first, create the directories, then create a new file to write.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class TestDir {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dirPath = "C:\\user\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2\\";
        String fileName = "filename.txt";

        Path path = Paths.get(dirPath);
        if(!Files.exists(path)) {
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(dirPath + fileName), "utf-8"))) {
            writer.write("something");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now that you have completely changed your answer from the deleted one, you are using the exact same suggestion I gave with `Files.createDirectories`...

Comment: @Eugene yup, probably mine is more error-catcher

Comment: uuuups, my bad, haven't paid attention

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("C:\\user\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2\\filename.txt");
Files.createDirectories(file.getParentFile().toPath());
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.write("jora");
writer.close();
```

Comment: I didn't get the expected result.